# MongoDB equivalent to Text Field in SQL

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

Does MongoDB have an equivalent to the "Text" field in SQL? If not, what is the recommended Field type to store large chunk of text?

Comment: That is not required. Everything you store is converted to binary format and then it is stored on disk. Mongo has limit on document size and not on field

Comment: Okay, but since I am using MongoEngine, and I need to define this field in my `class Something(Document):` , shall I just use `StringField()` for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MongoEngine then yes a StringField is what you want for storing text.